# Servlet Filter always redirects to login page

Tags: jsf, servlets, authentication, filter, cdi

I am implementing my system security with JSF, CDI and Servlet Filter. What happens is that every time I connect, the system redirects me to the home page, but when I click on any other link, the system redirects to the login page again.

I suspect that the scope of some CDI bean may be wrong, but I can not track it.

Can someone help me?

**Servlet Filter**

```
package com.br.pentagono.controler;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebFilter;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebFilter("/paginas/*")
public class AutorizacaoFilter implements Filter {

    @Inject
    LoginBean loginBean;

    public AutorizacaoFilter() {
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        if (loginBean.getIsLogado() == false && !request.getRequestURI().endsWith("/index.xhtml")
                && !request.getRequestURI().contains("/javax.faces.resource/")) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");

            System.out.println(request.getContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");

        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }

    }

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

}
```

**Login Bean**

```
package com.br.pentagono.controler;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.NoResultException;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import com.br.pentagono.model.Usuario;
import com.br.pentagono.repository.Usuarios;
import com.br.pentagono.util.jsf.JSFUtil;

@Named(value = LoginBean.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final String PAGINA_INICIAL = "paginas/home?faces-redirect=true";
    protected static final String BEAN_NAME = "loginMB";

    @Inject
    private Usuarios usuarios;
    private Usuario usuarioBanco = null;
    private Usuario usurioLogado;
    private String email;
    private String senha;
    private Boolean isLogado = false;

    public String login() {

        if (StringUtils.isBlank(email) && StringUtils.isBlank(senha)) {
            JSFUtil.retornarMensagemErro("Erro no Login", "Preencha os campos E-Mail e Senha!", null);
            this.setIsLogado(false);
        }

        try {
            usuarioBanco = usuarios.lerPorEmail(this.email);
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
            JSFUtil.retornarMensagemErro("Erro no Login", "Usuário não existe.", null);
            this.setIsLogado(false);
            return null;
        }

        if (null == usuarioBanco) {
            JSFUtil.retornarMensagemErro("Erro no Login", "Usuário ou Senha não encontrados", null);
            this.setIsLogado(false);
            return null;
        }

        if (!senha.equals(usuarioBanco.getSenha())) {
            JSFUtil.retornarMensagemErro("Erro no Login", "Dados incorretos!", null);
            this.setIsLogado(false);
            return null;
        }

        this.setIsLogado(true);
        this.setUsurioLogado(usuarioBanco);
        return this.getHome();
    }

    public String logout() {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().invalidateSession();
        return "/index?faces-redirect=true";
    }

    public String getHome() {
        return LoginBean.PAGINA_INICIAL;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public Usuario getUsurioLogado() {
        return usurioLogado;
    }

    public void setUsurioLogado(Usuario usurioLogado) {
        this.usurioLogado = usurioLogado;
    }

    public Boolean getIsLogado() {
        return isLogado;
    }

    public void setIsLogado(Boolean isLogado) {
        this.isLogado = isLogado;
    }

}
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>Faturamento</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>omega</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.SECRET</param-name>
        <param-value>@</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.SUBMIT</param-name>
        <param-value>partial</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default).
                    See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6LZwoAAEhRyntK2v-GMRR</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>6L0P7IBu</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>xhtml</extension>
        <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>2</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/paginas/erro/403.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/paginas/erro/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/paginas/erro/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager</resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>AutorizacaoFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.br.pentagono.controler.AutorizacaoFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AutorizacaoFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/paginas/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

        <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


</web-app>
```

Comment: I just want to check, can you confirm that after the `login()` method is invoked, `getIsLogado()` returns true?

Comment: Where do you call the login method on the login bean ? It seems to be missing

Comment: Yes returns true only at login time. After that, it returns false.
I'm calling the method on the index.xhtml page. I am using this page as a login page.